# How Convert Date Lists to DateRanges List in c#

Tags: c#, linq, date-range

How can `List<DateTime>` to `List<List<DateTime>>` that difference is `1`:

for example List is

```
var list = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(2023, 05, 02),
    new DateTime(2023, 05, 03),
    new DateTime(2023, 05, 04),
    new DateTime(2023, 05, 10),
    new DateTime(2023, 05, 11),
    new DateTime(2023, 05, 20),
};
```

and I want my method return this List

```
{
    2023-05-02,
    2023-05-03,
    2023-05-04
},
{
    2023-05-10,
    2023-05-11
},
{
    2023-05-20
}
```

Comment: I'd probably do this without LINQ, personally. Do you have any code *attempting* to do this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping and build the answer with a help of *Linq*, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static List<List<DateTime>> Solve(IEnumerable<DateTime> source) {
  List<List<DateTime>> result = new();
 
  if (source is null)
    return result;

  foreach (var date in source.OrderBy(item => item)) 
    if (result.Count > 0 && result.Last().Last().AddDays(1) == date)
      result.Last().Add(date);
    else
      result.Add(new List<DateTime>() { date });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `result.Last().Last().AddDays(1) == date` i'd use `dt - result.Last().Last()).TotalDays > 1`. Then it works also if they have a time portion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LINQ answer:

```
List<List<DateTime>> result =
    list
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            new[] { list.Take(1).ToList() }.ToList(),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                if (x.Subtract(a.Last().Last()).Days != 1)
                {
                    a.Add(new List<DateTime>());
                }
                a.Last().Add(x);
                return a;
            });
```

That gives:

[image: results]

NB: This assumes that `list` is ordered already (as per the list in the question).

---

Or as a handy extension method:

```
public static List<List<T>> Aggregate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<List<List<T>>, T, bool> isCurrent)
{
    List<List<T>> result = new() { new List<T>() };
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext())
        {
            result.Last().Add(e.Current);
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (!isCurrent(result, e.Current))
                {
                    result.Add(new List<T>());
                }
                result.Last().Add(e.Current);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now it's:

```
List<List<DateTime>> result =
    list
        .Aggregate((a, x) => x.Subtract(a.Last().Last()).Days == 1);
```

Comment: @Ralf - Yes, all answers fully tested where possible.

Comment: `var e` needs a `using`. Might as well keep `result.Last()` in a local. Also why not `yield return` the outer list?

Comment: @Charlieface - I don't like returning half exposed enumerables when the underlying source could be hot.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use LINQ if your logic needs to access next or previous items. A simple `foreach` is readable and efficient. Following works also if they have times:

```
List<List<DateTime>> result = new();
foreach (DateTime dt in list.OrderBy(d => d))// omit OrderBy if the list is already sorted
{
    if(result.Count == 0 || (dt - result[^1].Last()).TotalDays > 1)
    {
        result.Add(new List<DateTime>{dt});
    }
    else
    {
        result[^1].Add(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: index operator is not work in C#7.3

Comment: @Saratabaghchi: then use LINQ's `Last` or the indexer `result[result.Count-1]`. `Enumerable.Last` checks if the sequence has an indexer and uses that, so it's also efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through dates and check if the current date is less than 1 day away from the previous date. If it is, then add it to the current list, otherwise start a new list.

```
private List<List<DateTime>> GetListsOfConsecutiveDates(List<DateTime> dates)
{
    var result = new List<List<DateTime>>();

    var currentList = new List<DateTime>();
    var previousDate = dates.First();
    currentList.Add(previousDate);

    foreach (var date in dates.Skip(1))
    {
        if (date - previousDate <= TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
        {
            currentList.Add(date);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(currentList);
            currentList = new List<DateTime> { date };
        }

        previousDate = date;
    }

    result.Add(currentList);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully streaming version. No lists are created anywhere, the whole thing uses `IEnumerable`.

It assumes the original source is a `List<T>` (so that we can use an efficient `SkipTake` algorithm), and that it is already sorted.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupUp<T>(this List<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> isSameGroupFunc)
{
    for (var start = 0; start < source.Count; start++)
    {
        var end = start;
        while (end + 1 < source.Count)
        {
            if (!isSameGroupFunc(source[end], source[end + 1]))
                break;

            end++;
        }
        yield return SkipTake(source, start, end + 1);
        start = end;
    }
}

    
private static IEnumerable<T> SkipTake<T>(List<T> source, int start, int count)
{
    for (var i = start; i < count; i++)
        yield return source[i];
}
```

You use it like this:

```cs
var results = list.GroupUp((a, b) => a.AddDays(1) >= b);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ksaqFY)